# Null parameter in controller from ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

When a user clicks a save button, a JavaScript function uses AJAX to call the Controller and send over JSON data about the objects.

**JavaScript Function**

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Data/sendFridgeItems?items=" + JSON.stringify($scope.items.data),
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.items.data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            console.log("good!");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

**Controller**

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SendFridgeItems(string items)
    {
        fridge[] fridgeItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<fridge[]>(items);
        foreach (fridge item in fridgeItems)
        {
            bool exists = cookDB.fridges.AsEnumerable()
                .Any(x => x.Name == item.Name && x.Purchased == item.Purchased && x.Count == item.Count);
            if (!exists)
            {
                cookDB.fridges.Add(item);
                cookDB.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

It works, but I don't think the way of sending my data through the url parameter is correct in my situation, because the data will be big enough. I wanted to know if there is a better way to send my data to the controller?

I tried to send it this way, but the controller receives null value.

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/Data/sendFridgeItems",
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify($scope.items.data),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            console.log("good!");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });
```

**JSON of $scope.items.data**

```
[{"id":2,"name":"Item1","count":2,"type":"pcs.","purchased":"12/09/2017","wasted":"15/10/2017","cam":"Freezer","comment":"no comment","$$hashKey":"object:38"},{"id":3,"name":"Item2","count":30,"type":"g.","purchased":"15/01/1880","wasted":"21/03/1882","cam":"Cooler","comment":"commented","$$hashKey":"object:39"}]
```

**$scope.items**

```
$scope.items = {
    "count": 2,
    "data": [
      {
          "name": "Item1",
          "count": 2,
          "type": "pcs.",
          "purchased": "12/09/2017",
          "wasted": "15/10/2017",
          "cam": "Freezer",
          "comment": "no comment"
      },
  {
          "name": "Item2",
          "count": 30,
          "type": "g.",
          "purchased": "15/01/1880",
          "wasted": "21/03/1882",
          "cam": "Cooler",
          "comment": "Commented"
      }
    ]
};
```

**Fixed Controller For N.Ivanov's solution (this controller+ N.Ivanov's ajax = solution)**

```
public ActionResult SendFridgeItems(fridge[] items)
    {
        fridge[] fridgeItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<fridge[]>(items.ToString());
        foreach (fridge item in items)
        {
            bool exists = cookDB.fridges.AsEnumerable()
                .Any(x => x.Name == item.Name && x.Purchased == item.Purchased && x.Count == item.Count);
            if (!exists)
            {
                cookDB.fridges.Add(item);
                cookDB.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Make it like this and let me know `data: {"items":JSON.stringify($scope.items.data)},`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` field in ajax takes in an Object, you are giving it a string. Try and supply only your object, assuming that `$scope.items.data` is an object. If you give a bit more information on what `$scope` variable is, then I can give you a better answer.

**Code:**

`$.ajax({
        url: "/Data/sendFridgeItems",
        type: "POST",
        d̶a̶t̶a̶:̶ ̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶i̶t̶e̶m̶s̶.̶d̶a̶t̶a̶,̶
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            console.log("good!");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });`

Hope this helps!

---

**EDIT:**

Further inspection after you have provided the contents of `$scope.items.data` led me to notice that `$scope.items.data` is an array of objects. So in order for the ajax to work and actually supply valid JSON, try the following code:
`$.ajax({
        url: "/Data/sendFridgeItems",
        type: "POST",
        data: { "items": $scope.items.data },
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function () {
            console.log("good!");
        },
        error: function () {
            console.log("error");
        }
    });`

I have verified that `{ "item": $scope.items.data }` is a valid JSON through [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/)

Hope this solves your problem!

Comment: You could also try it like this: `data: { item:  JSON.stringify($scope.items.data)},` Hope this helps!

Comment: "data: $scope.items.data " fires "Invalid JSON primitive: Item1". And data: { item: JSON.stringify($scope.items.data)} fires "Invalid JSON primitive: item".  Quoting like data: { "item": JSON.stringify($scope.items.data) } fires same error. Variable is in the same scope with function. Added data of my $scope.items.data in JSON format to question

Comment: @Ryu I have updated my answer, check the *EDIT*, hope it works out!

Comment: I appreciate your help. Sorry I forgot to mention what $scope.items.data is an array. I have updated question, added $scope.items value. I checked JSON too, it is correct, but even with your new solution I catch xhr.responseText on error, and response text show me "Invalid JSON primitive: items".

Comment: If I use data: "{'foo':'foovalue', 'bar':'barvalue'}" instead of my data ajax give me no error, but controller recieve null value.

Comment: Finally I fixed it, the problem was in Controller. I used data: {items: $scope.desserts.data}, but controller needed fix too, instead of string I used "fridge[] items", fridge is a c# class with same fields as JS array, and also I removed line fridge[] fridgeItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<fridge[]>(items.ToString()), because now I don't need deserialize array.

Comment: @Ryu Glad to help out! Good luck with the project!

Answer (score 0):

Try JSON Parse to parse data as Object and send it to controller

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Data/sendFridgeItems",
    type: "POST",
    data: JSON.parse($scope.items.data),
    dataType: "json",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function () {
        console.log("good!");
    },
    error: function () {
        console.log("error");
    }
});
```